# try catch error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am getting underline in red color at my catch statement, not sure what is wrong the error that  I am getting is 'never thrown in body of a corresponding try statement' what does it mean? everything looks fine to me.

```
public void validateTriangle(int sidea, int sideb, int sidec) throws InvalidValueException {
    try {
        if ((sidea + sideb > sidec) || (sideb + sidec > sidea) || (sidea + sidec > sideb)) {
            findArea(side1, side2, side3);
        }
    } catch (InvalidValueException excep) {
        message = excep.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that `findArea` explicitly `throws InvalidValueException`

```
... findArea(...) throws InvalidValueException {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

*"never thrown in body of a corresponding try statement"* means exactly what it says: You've told the code to catch an `InvalidValueException`, but it's not thrown by any code within the `try` block. Apparently `findArea` doesn't throw that exception (and obviously your inline code doesn't).

A [`try/catch` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) is used to catch exceptions that occur within the `try` block and handle them (in the corresponding `catch` block), so there's no point in a `catch` for an exception that never occurs in the `try`. The IDE (and I believe the lint features of the `java` compiler tool) will flag that up for you on the basis that catching an error that isn't going to happen is probably a logic error.

Comment: Because InvalidValueException is a checked exception. If it extended RuntimeException it would compile fine (but would still make no sense ;-)).

Comment: @assylias: Indeed. I thought given noobprogrammer's username, I wouldn't get into checked vs. unchecked exceptions. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am right here..hello!! haha I am noob afterall! ok unriddle me this, I want to throw an exception if my 'IF' statement in the code is wrong how to do that?

Comment: @noobprogrammer: I don't know what you mean by *"...if my 'IF' statement...is wrong..."*, but to *throw* an exception, you use `throw` and create the `Exception` object, e.g.: `throw new InvalidValueException(...);` where `...` are the args (if any) for `InvalidValueException`. You'd also remove the `try/catch` because you're not trying to *handle* the exception, you're trying to *throw* it. Side note: If the problem is that one of the args is invalid, use the standard [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) instead. HTH,

Answer (score 1):

The code that runs inside the try block never will throw an `InvalidValueException`. That is what he is telling you.

The catch block is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this red line / compile-time error as your method

```
throws InvalidValueException
```

This means your method doesn't handle this exception & it will be passed on to the caller method. So in this case catch block is never going to be executed.

Answer (score -2):

Your `try-catch` overrides your `throws InvalidValueException`
You shoud remove your `try-catch`, or remove your `throws InvalidValueException`.

Comment: This is not right. It is perfectly valid to have a `throws` clause that lists exceptions that are not thrown by the currently implemented body of the method so the advice to remove `throws InvalidValueException` can't help. The issue is as other answers have said, that the body of code in the `try` block doesn't throw the caught exception.

Comment: I am not trying to remove the try-catch rather keep and workaround it.